# iterating over an array with for loop JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have an array of objects **(contacts)** and I need to write one function that  should check if firstName **(first parameter of the function)** is an actual contact's firstName and the given property **(prop is the second parameter of the function)** is a property of that contact. If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.

If **firstName** does not correspond to any contacts then return **"No such contact"**

If **prop** does not correspond to any valid properties then return **"No such property"**

I know what I need to do, the sudo I wrote it but to write it in actual JavaScript I am having a blockage.

Below what I wrote so far:

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    var value;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName === true && contacts[i].prop === true) {
            value = contacts[i].prop;
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us how your `contracts` array look like.

Comment: Contacts array added in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use break out of loop once you find a contact with given `firstName` and then check for the passed `prop` value and return message accordingly.

```js
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    var value = undefined;
    for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
            value = contacts[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(!value) {
        return 'No such contact';
    }
    
    if(!(prop in value)) {
        return 'No such property';
    }

    return value[prop];
}
console.log(lookUpProfile('Sherlock', 'likes'));
console.log(lookUpProfile('Harry', 'friends'));
console.log(lookUpProfile('John', 'likes'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.find` to check if the contact exists in the array:

```js
var contacts = [{firstname: "aaa", prop1: "val1"}, {firstname: "bbb", prop2: "val2"}];

function yourFunc(firstname, prop) {
  var ct = contacts.find(c => c.firstname === firstname);
  return ct ? ct[prop] || "No such property" : "No such contact";
}

console.log(yourFunc("aaa", 'prop2'));
console.log(yourFunc("aaa", 'prop1'));
console.log(yourFunc("bbb", 'prop2'));
console.log(yourFunc("bbb", 'prop1'));
console.log(yourFunc("ccc", 'prop1'));
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not work. it is an assignment and I need to use a for loop to iterate over the array/objects

Comment: @Hacene.N Just run the code snippet and you see it working. For code clarity and readability, instead of using traditional for loop, I use array.find

Comment: I know this works correctly. I mean my assignment will be rejected because it has to be done with a for loop. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    var contact;
    for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
            contact = contacts[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!contact) {
        return 'No such contact';
    }

    if(!contact[prop]) {
        return 'No such property';
    }

    return contact[prop];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not work. it is an assignment and I need to use a for loop to iterate over the array/objects.

Answer (score 0):

With a For Loop statement, it should be like this:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    var contact;
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
       if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName){
         contact = contacts[i];
         break;
       }
    }
    return contact ? ( contact[prop] ? contact[prop] : 'No such property') : 'No such contact';
}
```